# Show that the cross product is chiral

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Working from the definition that $\mathbf a \times \mathbf b =\|\mathbf a\|\|\mathbf b||\sin(\theta)$ I want to know why there are only two possible outcomes in a cartesian system. Since we already have that it's distributive and anticommutative, we can start by defining the possible outcomes of the product in its cartesian form.

$$\mathbf i\times \mathbf j=\pm \mathbf k \\ 
\mathbf j\times \mathbf k=\pm \mathbf i \\
\mathbf k\times \mathbf i=\pm \mathbf j$$

It appears there are actually 8 options. I know intuitively that this can't be the case or the cross product wouldn't be continuous over $\mathbf i,\mathbf j,\mathbf k$. The problem is I can't show it rigorously from first principles. (Without simply invoking that it has to be continuous and using counterexamples)

Comment: What do you mean, there are two possible outcomes?

Comment: there sre either three negatives or three positive signs

Comment: Ah, so your question is this? Show that there are exactly two continuous binary operations on $\mathbb R^3$ that satisfy the identity $\|f(\mathbf a,\mathbf b)\|=\|\mathbf a\|\|\mathbf b||\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: ... and such that the output is orthogonal to both inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 8 options, but there are only two indistinguishable families of the product.

Suppose we start with $i\times j = k, j\times k = i, k\times i= j$, swapping any orthogonal vector for its negative counterpart will be exactly equivalent to swapping the order of multiplication of two of the cross products. This gives us 4 of the options. Any further sign changes will only convert the cross product into one of these 4 variations. Hence choosing any of these 4 options is equivalent to redefining the coordinate system.

Now let's start with $j\times i = k, k\times j = i, i\times k= j$ or by the anticommutative law, $i\times j = -k, j\times k = -i, k\times i= -j$. Now changing the sign of any basis vector will allow us to convert between the remaining 4 cross products, but we cannot switch to the previous definition.

It is much easier to prove the distributive property of the cross product when we start with the cartesian definition. This argument applies just as well for both methods

Answer (score 2):

$$a \times b = \|a\|\|b\|\sin\theta n$$

where $n$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the plane containing $a$ and $b$ in the direction given by the right hand rule. The right hand rule has decided the sign of the vector.

$$i \times j = k$$
$$j \times k = i$$
$$k \times i = j$$

Note that $i \times j$ is not equal to $j \times i$.

$$j \times i = -k$$

If we use right hand rule in front of a mirror, then our counterpart in the mirror will be performing the left hand rule. Hence it is chiral.